# Loop through variables from a module

Tags: python-2.7

My goal is to produce a matrix from a series of 18090 lists of size 256 each.  Each list is referenced as newmodule.xlist#####.  How do I loop through the variables in newmodule.py to create the super matrix?

Answer (score 2):

The name of the variable can be constructed like this:

```
'xlist%05d' % i
```

You can grab the variable from the module like this:

```
getattr(newmodule, 'xlist%05d' % i)
```

To create a "2dim" list, i.e. a list of lists, do:

```
mat = [ getattr(newmodule, 'xlist%05d' % i) for in range(18090) ]
```

You'd probably want to convert that to a `numpy` 2dim array:

```
mat = numpy.array(mat)
```

or a `numpy` matrix:

```
mat = numpy.mat(mat)
```